# How can I create an new entry to a Database using GORM when I have a foreign key

Tags: go, go-gorm, goland

I want to use GORM to create a new entry in a table ("Mangas") that has a FK to another table ("Websites"), but unfortunately I can't manage to save the data after I create the variable even though I hava an entry in the table I want to save.

For clarifications, I want to have a 1:M relation between Websites-Mangas and Mangas-Chapters in a MySQL Database.

```golang
//in package modules
type Website struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name             string
    Url              string
    MangaSearchQuery string
    Mangas           []Manga
}
type Manga struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name      string
    Url       string
    ImgUrl    string
    Chapters  []Chapter
    WebsiteID uint
    Website   Website `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
}
type Chapter struct {
    gorm.Model
    Url     string
    WasRead bool
    MangaID uint
    Manga   Manga `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
}

//in main
    db := modules.GetDatabaseInstance()

    manga := modules.Manga{
        Model:   gorm.Model{},
        Name:    "Test",
        Url:     "none",
        ImgUrl:  "example.com",
        //WebsiteID: 1,
        Website: modules.Website{Url: "test1"},
    }
    db.Create(manga)
```

I tried multiple answers found, but none worked. I think they might be for other versions since there is quite the difference in each approach. Some required me to add an array of child elements to the parent table/interface, others to add an ID or the whole row reference to my interface before running db.Create, but each time I am receiving the same error: `panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value`

I'm using GO 1.21.0.
I don't know if my approach is wrong in the first place or is something else that I missed.

Also, sugestion on how I should improve the code is welcomed.

Comment: Not sure that solves the problem, but you aren't assigning any ids to your entities `Manga` and `Website`. As you can see [here](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#gorm-Model), `ID` is the primary key and therefore mandatory. Try `modules.Manga{Model: gorm.Model{ID: 1}, ... Website: modules.Website{Model: gorm.Model{ID: 1}, Url: "test1"}}`. But maybe it's not required here since you're not actually inserting something but just create a database from the model.

Comment: My bad, you aren't creating the DB but are actually inserting. So you must set the `IDs`. Maybe that even solves the problem.